# Возможность отправлять Push сообщения

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Здравствуйте!

Нужна ли мне статус разработчика, что бы включить возможность Push сообщений в своем проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, Вам нужен аккаунт разработчика. Как минимум для получения сертификатов.

Comment: Он стоит 99 долларов в год?

Comment: @IgorZexyy как ни печально, да.